# Is there any justification for that the line at infinity form a closed loop in projective plane _

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

In the book of *Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometry* by Greenberg, it is argued that in a projective plane, *the line at infinity forms a closed loop*; However the author does not provide any formal justification for this statement, so

Is there any formal proof of this statement from the axioms of projective plane ?

Comment: Do you understand how other lines form loops? If so, all lines are the same; the line at infinity is a loop too. In fact, any line $L$ can be viewed as a "line at infinity" since the points not on $L$ will be an affine plane.

Comment: Think about the model of the projective plane as a sphere with antipodes identified. What do lines look like in this model?

Answer (score 1):

The question comes down to what the author means by a closed loop.  I'll give an intuitive explanation.  And for this, I'll assume the P(2) space.

Think of the coordinate $\begin{bmatrix}2\\ 3\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.  This coordinate is on the line at infinity in the direction $(2,3)$.  In general, the coordinate $\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ lies on the line at infinity in the direction $(x,y)$.  So you see we have a point on the line of infinity in all directions.  And thus, the line at infinity forms a closed loop.

Comment: If I skip the problem about how you obtain "So you see we have a point on the line of infinity at all directions" for the time being, how such a conclusion allow you to argue that the line is a closed loop ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "closed loop".  I would say that there's a line at infinity at every direction.  This is analogous to being located at the origin with a unit circle placed on a graph.  Again, there is part of the unit circle in every direction.  We could accept this as the definition of a "closed loop", which the line at infinity satisfies.